# SharePoint 2013 - How to enable collapse view in a list with web part connection?

Tags: 2013, web-part, list-view, grouping, connected-web-parts

I have two lists that are connected in the same page via web part connection. This way, I can filter one of them using the other.

However, since there are many inputs, I would like the view to be in a collapsed way. When I do that by changing the grouping option in the view, even though I select "collapsed", it shows everything expanded.

Thus, is there a way to make them collapsed via SharePoint Designer or any other kind of customization.

### Regards

Guilherme P.